# How to only call left side of comma (,) separator

Tags: javascript, function, comma-operator

```js
const test = (
    (success) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS CALLED');
    },
    (error) => { 
        console.log('ERROR CALLED');
    }
);

test(); // output is **ERROR CALLED**
```

In the above javascript code, is there anyway to output **SUCCESS CALLED** without changing the definition

Comment: Why would one come up with such an expression at all? An assignment should be explicit. What is the comma good for? The success related arrow function will be immediately garbage collected.

Comment: You can leave the definition like it is and just output "SUCCESS CALLED". What is this game!?

Comment: @trincot: Cute solution. If this was a dumb interview question, that may have been what they were going for; you can't make *`test`* do it (at least, not without entering another scope where you can define a new `test`; this `const test` is locked), but you can just output it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

##### There is no way to do this

The *definition* of the comma operator is that it evaluates the expressions in order, from left-to-right, and the overall expression is the result of the final expression evaluated (the right-most). `test` *never* contains *any* information about the success-oriented function, so there is no way to make `test` invoke it without altering *something* in the definition of `test`.